# I created a subclass of the Rectangle class, but I'm only able to return the superclass' default values of x and y

Tags: java, inheritance, superclass

I'm working on a school project where I need to extend Java's default `Rectangle` class into a subclass called `MyRectangle`; the subclass has additional variables including `width` and `height`, and when I use a dot operator to print those values out I get the correct numbers in the output. However, when I try to do the same with the `x` and `y` values of my `MyRectangle` objects I always end up getting the default `x` and `y` values (0 and 0) even when I pass different values through parameters in my constructors. I thought that maybe renaming the parameters in my subclass' constructors and then assigning those new parameter's values to the superclass' `x` and `y` variables would fix the issue, but it only led to errors.
The desired outputs (with respect to `x` and `y`) would be:
x = 0 y = 0 // x = 5 y = 5 // x = 0 y = 0 // x = -10 y = 3

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Here's my code:

```
    class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    MyRectangle mr1 = new MyRectangle(0, 0, 4, 2, "blue", "red", true);
    MyRectangle mr2 = new MyRectangle(5, 5, 10, 3, "green");
    MyRectangle mr3 = new MyRectangle();
    MyRectangle mr4 = new MyRectangle(-10, 3, 10, 3, mr2.color);

    System.out.println( "x = " + mr1.x + " y = " + mr1.y + " width = " + mr1.width + " height = " + mr1.height + " color = " + mr1.color +" area = " + mr1.area() + " perimeter = " + mr1.perimeter()); //Prints info about mr1

    System.out.println( "x = " + mr2.x + " y = " + mr2.y + " width = " + mr2.width + " height = " + mr2.height + " color = " + mr2.color + " borderColor = " + mr2.borderColor + " area = " + mr2.area() + " perimeter = " + mr2.perimeter()); //mr2

    System.out.println( "x = " + mr3.x + " y = " + mr3.y + " width = " + mr3.width + " height = " + mr3.height + " color = " + mr3.color + " borderColor = " + mr3.borderColor + " area = " + mr3.area() + " perimeter = " + mr3.perimeter()); //mr3

    System.out.println( "x = " + mr4.x + " y = " + mr4.y + " width = " + mr4.width + " height = " + mr4.height + " color = " + mr4.color + " borderColor = " + mr4.borderColor + " area = " + mr4.area() + " perimeter = " + mr4.perimeter()); //mr4  }

    public static class MyRectangle extends Rectangle {
    public int width, height;
    public String color, borderColor;
    public boolean border;

    //MyRectangle has 3 constructors
    public MyRectangle() {
      super();
      width = height = 1;
    }

    public MyRectangle(int x, int y, int w, int h, String c) {
      super(x,y); 
      width = w;
      height = h;
      color = c;
    }

    public MyRectangle(int x, int y, int w, int h, String c, String bc, boolean b) {
      this(x,y,w,h,c);
      borderColor = bc;
      border = b;
    }
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation of `Rectangle`? What its constructors expect?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Rectangle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/awt/Rectangle.html) there is no constructor that receives x and y alone.

You have to modify your constructors to set those. For example:

```
  public MyRectangle(int x, int y, int w, int h, String c) {
     super(w, h);
     this.x = x;
     this.y = y;
     color = c;
  }
```